# event handling for a word instance inside c#

Tags: wpf, winapi, c#-4.0, office-interop, winforms-interop

I have a scenario in which I am currently displaying a word document inside a web browser control and we need a provision that while editing the document if user presses a key shortcut it will bring the focus out of that word document to some button outside the web browser control,but somehow I am not able to capture the event generated through word instance inside web browser control while editing the document.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Technology:C#4.0,MVVM architect,WPF

Note: We are creating this document by using method exposed by interop on a macro enabled template and then displaying it inside a web browser control

Comment: How are you editing with a web browser control?

Comment: Inside a web browser control i can display an instance of word and can perform any sort of editing operation which are available in word.